# How to find Test suite.xml execution status in Testng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to find the execution status of TestNG.xml whether the suite is completed or not.

I am executing multiple xml suites like:

```
testng.setSuites(suite1);
testng.run();
```

Now after all the thread hits `testng.run();`, I want to get the execution status of every single xml suite.

I am confused of testng.getStatus(), because what it returns is an int value and what does that value mean exactly.

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

1)click on your project
2)press F5
3)open project
4)at the end of project you will see TESTNG output